# Java - String manipulation within multiple-lines textfile

Tags: java, string

I came across this problem (NOT a school-related).
Original text file contains:

```
[Name1]
//Feature1.1
//Feature1.2
[Name2]
//Feature2.1
//Feature2.2
[Name3]
//Feature3.1
//Feature3.2
... and so on ...
```

What I want looks like this:

```
[Name1]//Feature1.1
[Name1]//Feature1.2  
[Name2]//Feature2.1
[Name2]//Feature2.2
[Name3]//Feature3.1
[Name3]//Feature3.2
... and so on ...
```

I need help on the algorithm (NOT code) how to make the target file.
I appreciate any helps.

This is what I got in the logic:
I separated the input into two List.(the number in front is the line number in the input file)
List1:

```
1[Name1]
4[Name2]
7[Name3]
```

List2:

```
2//Feature1.1
3//Feature1.2
5//Feature2.1
6//Feature2.2
8//Feature3.1
9//Feature3.2
```

Then I merge them together into finalList, using for loop and conditions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < List1.size() - 1; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < List2.size() - 1; j++)
   {
                           // this get the number 1, 4, or 7                    
      if(Integer.parseInt(List1.get(i).substring(0,List1.get(i).indexof("[")) < Integer.parseInt(List1.get(i).substring(0,List2.get(j).indexof("["))) // the second part get 2,3,5,6,8, or 9
      {
         finalList.add(List1.get(i) + List2.get(j));    
      }
   }
}
```

After this, what I got is below:

```
1[Name1]2//Feature1.1
1[Name1]3//Feature1.2
1[Name1]5//Feature2.1
1[Name1]6//Feature2.2
1[Name1]8//Feature3.1
1[Name1]9//Feature3.2
4[Name2]5//Feature2.1
4[Name2]6//Feature2.2
4[Name2]8//Feature3.1
4[Name2]9//Feature3.2
7[Name3]8//Feature3.1
7[Name3]9//Feature3.2
```

My wanted ones is:

```
1[Name1]2//Feature1.1
1[Name1]3//Feature1.2
4[Name2]5//Feature2.1
4[Name2]6//Feature2.2
7[Name3]8//Feature3.1
7[Name3]9//Feature3.2
```

After this step, I will edit the string in each element of the finalList into this:

```
[Name1]//Feature1.1
[Name1]//Feature1.2
[Name2]//Feature2.1
[Name2]//Feature2.2
[Name3]//Feature3.1
[Name3]//Feature3.2
```

Again, thank for all suggestions and idea. 
I have been struggle on this problem for a while. The key point is I DON'T understand the logic behind to get this done.

Comment: Please show what have you tried to solve this.

Comment: Read each line in and format it how you want. What's the problem you're having with the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get this problem solved.
Here is what i did:

```
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
    if (inputLine.substring(0, 1).equals("["))
    {
        nameList.add(inputLine.substring(0, inputLine.indexOf("]")+1));
        checkPoint = nameList.size() - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        finalList.add(nameList.get(checkPoint) + inputLine );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your motivations by pushing me to dig deeper in the code.